# How to generate DSA signature keys for audio file in JAVA

Tags: java, dsa

I have a audio file(choose extension whatever is the easiest to work with). How to prepare data(a message in this code) for DSA algorithm?

```
String alg = "DSA";
        KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(alg);//pobranie instancji algorytmu "DSA" rzuca wyjatek no such algorithm..
        KeyPair keyPair = kg.genKeyPair(); //pobieramy pare kluczy prywatny i publiczny
        Signature sign = Signature.getInstance(alg); // generowany zostaje podpis implementujacy konkretny algorytm w tym wypadku DSA
        SignedObject so = new SignedObject(message, keyPair.getPrivate(), sign); // podpisywanie otrzymywanej wiadomosci -> message, zwracany jest podpisany obiekt     
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("wynikDSA.txt")); // tworze nowy bufferred writer ktory umozliwa zapis do pliku
        verify(so,new Czytelnik(keyPair.getPublic()),sign,bw); // weryfikujemy czy klucz publiczny nowoutworzonego czytelnika pasuje do podpisu, przekazujemy bw aby moc zapisac dane do pliku
        bw.write("klucz prywatny " + keyPair.getPrivate()  //wpisywanie do pliku klucza prywatnego i publicznego
                + "\nklucz publiczny " + keyPair.getPublic());
        ShortCuts.addShortcutsIntoTheFile(bw, message); //dopisanie skortow MD5 i SHA-1 do pliku
        System.out.println(keyPair.getPrivate()); //wyspianie na konsoli klucza prywatnego na konsoli, ponizej  publicznego
        System.out.println(keyPair.getPublic());
        bw.close();
```

Comment: DSA is not suitable for large message encryption. If I am correct, a DSA of 1024bits should not be able to encrypt a message bigger than 128 bytes. So you audio file cannot be bigger than that.

Comment: @gigadot it had no problem with "fasbufbsafsafa"   *10000

Comment: "fasbufbsafsafa" *10000 is "fasbufbsafsafa" repeats 10000 times or value of "fasbufbsafsafa" multiply by 10000?